# Подключение к базе данных из докера, с сетью host

Tags: сеть, docker, docker-compose, локальная-сеть

Один контейнер, сильно завязанн на свои адреса при работе. Астериск. Он включается с сетью host. Но он также подключается к базе данных. Как узнать адрес контейнера с бд в этом случае?

```
version: '2.4'
volumes:
  astdb:
  voicemail:
  pgdata:
services:
  asterisk:
    #image: azielke/asterisk:lts
    build: ./docker/asterisk/
    container_name: asterisk
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Moscow
    volumes:
      - "./asterisk:/etc/asterisk:ro"
      - "./odbcinst.ini:/etc/odbcinst.ini:ro"
      - "./odbc.ini:/etc/odbc.ini:ro"
      - "astdb:/var/lib/asterisk/db"
      - "voicemail:/var/spool/asterisk/voicemail"
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: asterisk
      POSTGRES_USER: asterisk
      POSTGRES_DB: asterisk
    volumes:
      - "pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
```

Как не выкидывать db по портам в этом случае?

```
# docker network inspect asterdocker_default
[
    {
        "Name": "asterdocker_default",
        "Id": "58c21386cd625c803976e2a323a1f0756dfb7096804c52cd62d4119f281f5997",
        "Created": "2021-08-09T22:52:08.393852519Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "040d5fecc26d4e1e8bd65217fe5e7a34dccd35e8b10fe35a1eb0355dd7f11110": {
                "Name": "asterdocker_db_1",
                "EndpointID": "98cf10ccde83d58a4ae3b01d3a1c6195e5e95b268e244f1523452566b045a802",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "asterdocker",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.0"
        }
    }
]
```

нужный хост имеет адрес 172.18.0.2 - как его отресолвить?

Comment: Если сеть host, то и адрес у контейнера будет как у хоста.

Comment: @user7860670 - мне нужна обратка

Comment: ¿Что подразумевается под словом "обратка"?

Comment: обратное твоему предположению)

Comment: написанно ж что хочу к бд подключаться из сети в режиме хоста

Comment: @eri вы же можете указать для второго контейнера адрес подключения как `DSN=postgresql://asterisk:asterisk@db/asterisk`. внутри контейнера будет доступна база

Comment: @SeniorPomidor не работает. ресолвер не отрабатывает db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нельзя одновременно иметь и `host` и `bridge` типы сетей в композе.

По умолчанию композ сам решает кому какой IP установить при старте. Но так как этот метод не детерминирован, то нам нужно самому определять нужные IP-шники контейнеров

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_DB=metrics"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=user"
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.20
        ipv6_address: 2001:3984:3989::20

  app:
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    network_mode: host
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        apt-get update && apt-get -y install iputils-ping telnet
        ping -c 10  172.16.238.20
        sleep 10000


networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    enable_ipv6: true
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
          gateway: 172.16.238.1
        - subnet: 2001:3984:3989::/64
          gateway: 2001:3984:3989::1
```

кусок логов

```
app_1  | Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
app_1  | PING 172.16.238.20 (172.16.238.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.122 ms
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.168 ms
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.160 ms
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
app_1  | 64 bytes from 172.16.238.20: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
app_1  |
app_1  | --- 172.16.238.20 ping statistics ---
app_1  | 10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9199ms
app_1  | rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.055/0.087/0.168/0.043 ms
```

Comment: спасибо за пример. а так бы забрать автоматический адрес в переменную и передать в env второму контейнеру - было б идеально. а пока вариант со статикой подойдет. не было б колизий с подсетями других проектов.